# --region versus --regions argument in cloudml-samples/flowers/sample.sh

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

In Google's sample code found at [cloudml-samples/flowers/sample.sh](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/flowers/sample.sh#L66-L69), between lines 66 and 69, is the argument "region":

```
# Tell CloudML about a new type of model coming.  Think of a "model" here as
# a namespace for deployed Tensorflow graphs.
gcloud ml-engine models create "$MODEL_NAME" \
  --region us-central1
```

Shouldn't "region" be replaced with "regions" to avoid an error?

(I'm not in position to submit a PR about this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be pushed in the next couple of days.